# Outlook 2010 Cabinet Folders

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

Does anyone know if there exists a keyboard and mouse click sequence (or any type of shortcut) to be able to open a folder and all corresponding subfolders under the Cabinet folder in Outlook 2010?  Something like holding down the CTRL key and clicking on the parent folder to open it and all subfolders beneath it.

Answer (score 1):

Right arrow <kbd>-></kbd> or the <kbd>+</kbd> on Num Pad will expand a folder. Then to expand subfolders of selected folder use <kbd>*</kbd> on the Num Pad.

Here is a list of other [useful keyboard shortcuts](http://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/keyboardshortcuts.htm#general-actions) for Outlook.

Comment: If that answered your question, feel free to mark it as such.